# javax.persistence - drop items of a oneToMany-relationship

Tags: java, database

I have a java.uitl.Set which is filled with one of my persistence object n1. this set is a private member of my persistence object n2. They are in an onetomany relationship. So n2 can have many of n1 but n1 can only have one n2.

Here is my problem;
I add a n1 to the set of n2 and commit it. Done in perfection. n1 is now in the n1-table and n2 is updated in the n2-table. But if I remove this n1 from the set again and merge n2, n2 is updated but the removed n1 wont drop from the n1-table. I tried with cascadetype and with orphanRemoval or however it is called. can somebody help me with this?

Thanks,
Basti

EDIT:
Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a orphan removal problem. Put the following annotation on the @OneToMany site and not on the @ManyToOne site:

`@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})`

Comment: it is already set to the onetomany side. on the manytoone side you cant set the flag for orphanremoval. an orphan discribes an item which stands allone, because it does not belong any longer to the manytoone relationship. on the manytoone-side it wouldnt make any sense. i just mentioned manytoone to explain the relationship

Comment: anyways, your post helped me. i was stupid, turbo mega awesome stupid. had cascadetype just for merge. how shall orphanremoval allow to delete droped items if cascadetype says no -.- i am an idiot, sorry

Comment: Something like this happen to me too, all the time :-)